# Как правильно сказать - "она была в неглиже" или "она была неглиже"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

-

Answer (score 2):

Хороший вопрос.

В современном языке оба варианта равнонормативны, но тут есть небольшая тонкость. У слова два значения, оба связанны с легкой, утренней одеждой или нижним бельём, полуодетым видом. Но это две разные части речи.

1. Историческое существительное "неглиже" означало одежду, непосредственно надеваемые предметы. В этом случае возможно только **"была в неглиже"**, как "была в пальто", хотя "носила неглиже", как "носила пальто".
2. Современное значение "неглиже" выступает в качестве наречия и означает сам внешний вид, полуодетого или легко и небрежно одетого человека. В этом случае правильнее вроде бы **"была неглиже"**, как "была полуодета". Однако первое, устаревшее в целом, значение сохранилось в сочетании "в неглиже", которое тоже используется в качестве наречия. Таким образом **"была в неглиже"** тоже нормативно.

Answer (score 1):

Оба варианта верны, потому что слово неглиже многозначное. 
 НЕГЛИЖЕ́ (устар.).

1. нескл., ср. Домашняя, непритязательная, несколько небрежная одежда. 
    *Сидит он этак на терраске, в неглиже, слизывает пенки с варенья.*
2. прил. неизм. устар.
   Одетый в легкое, простое домашнее платье *Я неглиже.*